# The link list is not printing the value after first iteration

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I just made a program of double linked list in which I was trying to print the values after every insertion operation done.

After first insertion no value is being printed but from the second insertion the value is printing fine(except the first one).

I am hereby attaching the full code

```
// Double Linked List
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next,*prev;
};

struct node *head;

struct node *getnewnode(int);
void insertathead(int);
void insertattail(int);
void display();
void rev_display();

void main()
{
    char c;
    int n,n1;

    clrscr();
    head = NULL;
    do
    {
        printf("\n Enter Data Element");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Press 1 to insert at beginning \n Press 2 to insert at the end");
        scanf("%d", &n1);

        if(n1 == 1)
        {
            insertathead(n);
            display();
            rev_display();
        }
        if(n1 == 2)
        {
            insertattail(n);
            display();
            rev_display();
        }
        printf("Do you wish to enter more (Y/N)");
        c = getch();
    } while(c == 'Y' || c == 'y');
    getch();
}

struct node *getnewnode(int x)
{
    struct node *newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data = x;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->prev = NULL;
    return(newnode);
}

void insertathead(int x)
{
    struct node *temp = getnewnode(x);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        head->prev = temp;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = head;
    printf("Forward:\n");

    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void rev_display()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = head;

    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    while(temp->prev != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
}

void insertattail(int x)
{
    struct node *temp = getnewnode(x);
    struct node *t;

    t = head;

    while(t->next != NULL)
    {
        t = t->next;
    }
    t->next = temp;
    temp->prev = t;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation so that this is legible.

Comment: You have a typo: `rev_dispaly` is not `rev_display`.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks I found that mistake Please rectify my other one

Comment: My eyes hurt! Use a **readable** indentation style. Add error-checking and get comfortable with the debugger.

Comment: What is the problem in indentation style?

Comment: I sometimes wonder if an OP can actually see what they posted. Is that really what your code looks like in your editor?

Comment: `while(temp->next!=NULL)` at `display` : `temp->next` --> `temp` (`rev_dispaly` similar mistake)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am not able to understand what is the problem please elaborate

Comment: You have used tabs in the code. While this appears correct when you use an 8 character tab, when it is posted it does not show correctly. You must replace the tab characters with actual spaces (either 2 or 4 spaces). Otherwise, we cannot see what the code means.

Comment: @user6547375 The last element is not displayed.(because it falls out of the loop before display last element)

Comment: There are several places where you use `**dispaly** when it seems you should be using **display** Fix those with the indentation so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The first element is not being displayed. the last element is being dislayed as far as I know

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @user6547375 If the element is  one, it is the last element. try test (change `display();  rev_display();` --> `display();`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am not getting what changes should be done in display() and rev_display();

Comment: The reason for performing test only in `display`, because the display is mixed.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the definition of the while loop. You stop when you reach a setting with no previous entry. You should stop when the current entry is NULL

Also note that in your original you call  `rev_display()` but you defined the function as `rev_dispaly()`. That typo should be fixed.

You also assume that insertattail() never has a case in which the list is empty (`head == NULL`) I will show how that occurs after the `rev_display` fix.

```
void rev_display()
  {
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    // This correctly finds the last entry
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
      {
        temp=temp->next;
      }
    /* This will stop when you reach the entry with no previous entry */
    while(temp->prev!=NULL)
      {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->prev;
      }
}
```

The code should really be

```
void rev_display()
  {
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    // This correctly finds the last entry
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
      {
        temp=temp->next;
      }
    /* This will correctly include the head as well in the print */
    while(temp != NULL)
      {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->prev;
      }
}
```

You do not check for the empty list case in `insertattail()`.

```
void insertattail(int x)
  {
    struct node *temp=getnewnode(x);
    struct node *t;
    t=head;
    // Note that this assumes that the list is not empty
    while(t->next!=NULL)
      {
        t=t->next;
      }
    t->next=temp;
    temp->prev=t;
  }
```

This needs to check for the empty list.

```
void insertattail(int x)
  {
    struct node *temp=getnewnode(x);
    struct node *t;
    // First check if the list is empty
    if(head==NULL)
      {
        head=temp;
        head->next = NULL;
        head->prev = NULL;     
      }
    else
      {
        t=head;
        // This list is not empty so find the end
        while(t->next!=NULL)
          {
            t=t->next;
          }
          t->next=temp;
          temp->prev=t;
        }
  }
```